# How to create foreign key between two different windows azure blob storage files

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a two different windows azure blob storage files. Is there a way to create foreign key relationships between two azure blob storage, just like between two oracle tables.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's infeasible. Azure Blob Storage is not a relational database per its architecture.

Comment: Does my reply solve your question? If my reply is helpful, please mark it as answer, which will help others find and resolve similar problem quickly.